# login with twitter in nodejs and passport

Tags: node.js, express, twitter, passport.js, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use twitter API and login with twitter. I saw a video in YouTube that write this code.
I use this librarys

> express, express-session, passport, passport-twitter

```
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
   secret: '',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
}));

const passport = require('passport');
const strategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;

passport.use(new strategy({
  consumerKey: '',
  consumerSecret: '',
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8085/twitter/return'

},(token, tokenSecret, profile, callback) =>{
  console.log('token '+token);
  console.log('tokenSecret '+tokenSecret);
  return callback(null, profile) ;
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, callback)=>{
  callback(null, user) ;

 });

passport.deserializeUser((obj, callback)=>{
   callback(null, obj) ;
  });

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const get = require('./api/v1/get');
app.use('/get', get);

app.get('/twitter/login', passport.authenticate('twitter'));
app.get('/twitter/return', passport.authenticate('twitter', 
     {failureRedirect: '/get'}), (req, res)=>{
      res.redirect('/get')
})
```

it work and I can get the Token and Token secret. but I cant't understand this token is for which user in my database.
twitter callback this url

> /twitter/return?oauth_token=E_kY_gAAAAAA4LMMAAABZV&oauth_verifier=jz8apFk29iaN7nt8HYfIjFIg9K8

can I use oauth_token or oauth_verifier to understand which user login? how can I underestand?

Answer (score 1):

Check the full explanation of the passport-twitter package: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter. It explains how to save in DB and auth your users through Twitter account.

Basically, what you need to do is to add the code to save (or find if it already exists) the user in DB in the Strategy's callback. Look at the 'Configure Strategy' section in the Readme.

Then, you are ready to use the Twitter strategy like you'r already doing.